# Angular: how to iterate through all indices in an array except the final index using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, iterator, iteration

***I have an array...***

```
$scope.arr = ["first", "second", true];
```

**I am using ng-repeat iterate through and bind each index value to a `<p>` tag like so...**

```
<div ng-repeat="value in arr">
    <p ng-bind="value"></p>
</div>
```

**How do I ng-bind every value in the array except the final index `"last"` value? Like...**

```
<div>
    <p>first</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>second</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean the obvious one that comes to mind if just an if inside of the ng-repeat that doesn't output if the index is equal to the size of the array.

Edit: `limitTo` looks like what you want: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try using the "limitTo" filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in arr | limitTo : arr.length-1">
    <p ng-bind="value"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The below snippet can solve the requirement of yours

```js
    angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
          $scope.arr = ["first", "second", true];
        }
      ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <h1>hi</h1>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <div ng-repeat="value in arr | limitTo: arr.length -1">
      <p>{{value}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

with a quick look, use the below syntax

```
<div ng-repeat="value in arr" ng-if="value!='last'">
    <p ng-bind="dataset"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nvm that worked. For what I am doing Cylowatt's answer is better though. You still get an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Just use {{ value.binding }}...

{{ value }}

easy and simple.

Comment: of course, add the filter in the ng-repeat:   <div ng-repeat="value in arr | limitTo: arr.length -1">
      <p>{{value}}</p>
    </div>.

Comment: It may be useful to move your comment into your answer, and provide more detail.